# What is missing in my code to reach this output?

Tags: python, output

**What is missing in my code to reach this output?**

```
b = lambda x: _______
    print(b(1))
    print(b(3))

output: 1
        3
```

Answer (score 1):

Return what is going in..

```
b = lambda x: x
```

Comment: Thanks.

i have a few more:  

c = lambda x, y: _______
print(c(1, 3))
print(c(2, 5))

output:
4
7

if you don't mind helping

Comment: @MosheWalters c = lambda x, y : x+y

Comment: @MosheWalters If the above main answer solves your issue, please mark is solved for others. Thanks